# Add number of hours to 24 hour clock

Tags: javascript, datetime

This function adds a number of hours to a 24 hour clock:

```
/**
 * @param {Integer} now The current hours
 * @param {Integer} add The number of hours to add
 */
function addHours(now, add){
    var h = (now + add) % 24;

    return h < 0 ? 24 + h : h;
};
```

- `addHours(2, 5) //7`
- `addHours(23, 5) //4`
- `addHours(23, -5) //18`
- `addHours(72, 3) //3`
- `addHours(0, 0) //0`

The output should always be an integer in the range of 0 - 23.

I can't see any problem with it, but maybe you can. Please let me know if it can be improved or if there are any bugs.

Comment: Other that the inappropriate parameter name `now`, there is not much you could say about it code-wise. However what I'd like to question its usefulness, which seems very limited.

Comment: @RoToRa I'm using as part of a set of unit tests. I have to test some other functions that manipulate time, and this one helps keep the tests readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tiny question ;)

- As @Rotora mentioned, `now` is not a fantastic parameter name, it conveys that I need to only pass who late it is 'now', `add` is a verb, also not brilliant as parameter naming goes
- `addHours( -500 , -100 )` returns `-0`, is that what you want ?
- You have 4 lines of comment, 3 lines of code, 1 blank line, perhaps you have to much comment ? Try to not need comments by working harder on parameter names.
- Since adding is commutative ( order does not matter ), I would consider naming the function sumHours and name the parameters hours1 and hours2

  ```
  function sumHours(hours1, hours2){
      var sum = (hours1 + hours2) % 24;
      return sum < 0 ? 24 + sum : +sum;
  };
  ```

Comment: Thanks for finding the `-0` bug, actually I didn't know `-0` was even a number. Also your other points are helpful.

Comment: [Negative zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero#Comparisons) might not be that big of a problem for you, as it [behaves very much like positive zero](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6807619/1157100). You would have to go out of your way to test `1 / -0 === Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` to detect negative zero.